# Watching an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget

I have a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 app. By "new", I mean, it is a brand new project created via Visual Studio 2017. From the command-line, I can type `dotnet run` and my app will load just fine. However, I want to have hot reloads during my development. So, I tried running `dotnet watch run`. When I run this command, I receive the following error:

*No executable found matching command "dotnet-watch"*

I assumed this meant that the [DotNet Watcher Tools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools) were not installed. However, I verified that they are in fact installed via Nuget. What am I missing? How do I watch an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app for changes?

Thank you

Comment: Have you added `Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools` to the .csproj file?

Comment: @i'myourhuckleberry - What do you mean "adding to the .csproj file?". I didn't see any documentation about that.

Comment: it's all in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch best of luck!

Comment: Awesome! I'm not sure how I missed this. Either way, thank you SO much for your help. I now have watching working.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2 of this tool, I was receiving the same error. My mistake was installing the package via NuGet. Instead, follow the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch

1. Add a Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools package reference to the **.csproj file**:

   <ItemGroup>
       <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>
2. Install the Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools package by running the following command:

   dotnet restore